# How can i build a db_select, ->condition comparing a field with a value in drupal with php

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

im trying to make a field with the results of a sql in php . im trying to make a condition with the field "manifestacionType" and compare with value 'compuesta'.

The problem is that i dont know to do that. I think the problem is that n.manifestacionType dont access to the real value of this field and never compare. I try some things like ['und']['value'], with ->node, but nothing work!!! i dont know to built this. im so desesperated!

Here is my code:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        ->condition('n.type', 'manifestacion_cultural', '=')
        ->condition('status', 1,'=')
      **->condition('n.manifestacionType', 'compuesta', '=')**
                ->orderBy('title');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();
return $result;
```

the result of this is nothing, and if i remove the condition in **, i receive all of 'manifestacion_cultural' with status =1 (publicated). I need to add a filter that with a condition to receive only with 'manifestacionType' (this a field) = 'compuesta'. Most probably there are some better solutions for creating a field or ways to do this querys but i dont know how.

thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I unerstood your question correctly, so, please correct me if doesn't what you want:

You have a field called "manifestacion Type", then you want to obtain those node results where the content type is "manifestacion_cultural" and "manifestacion Type" field value is equal to "compuesta".

In that case, you need to built a db_select using a join between the node table and the "manifestacion Type" field  table, please access to your database and check the name of the "manifestacion Type" field table, drupal always create a field table like this: field_data_fiel_machine_name

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'manifestacion_cultural', '=')
  ->condition('status', 1, '=');
  ->join('fiel_data_manifestacionType_table', 'mt', 'n.nid = mt.nid'); 
  ->condition('mt.fiel_manifestacionType_value', 'compuesta', '=');
  ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();
```